# Validate numbers consecutives in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, validation

I have an array:

```
var aNumbers = [1,2,1,3,4,4,5];
```

I need validate two conditions:

**First**, I need to know if the array contains a number, I have a function that find the element. (*No problem, It's working!*)

```
function include(arr,obj) {
   return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}

include(aNumbers,1);//true
include(aNumbers,6);//false
```

**Second** , I need one function to validate the number in sequence, something like this:

```
function consecutive(arr,obj){
    //code
}
```

The result expected....

```
consecutive(aNumbers,6);//true
consecutive(aNumbers,7);//false
```

**In summary:** I need to add a number that exists in my array or be consecutive to the maximum.

```
if(include(aNumbers, newNumber)){
    aNumbers.push(newNumber); 
}else if(consecutive(aNumbers, newNumber)){
    aNumbers.push(newNumber);
}else{
    alert('Number not valid!!!');
}
```

*I need help with my function to validate consecutive!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming array is sorted

```
function consecutive(arr,obj){
    return arr[arr.length - 1] + 1 === obj;
}
```

If not

```
function consecutive(arr,obj){
    return Math.max.apply(Math, arr) + 1 === obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's Working!

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to check whether the input is equal to the last element in the array plus 1?

```
function consecutive(arr,obj){
    return (arr[arr.length - 1] + 1) === obj;
}
```

Error handling not included and up to you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but, my array contains numbers duplicate, `var aNumbers= [1,2,3,2,4,3,5]`